# How to hide Quick Launch on a Modern Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, modern-pages, quick-launch

I have a SharePoint Online site using Modern pages. I know that under Navigation Settings you can turn off the Quick Launch, but it only appears to work on classic pages (Site Settings, Site Content, Publishing Pages library, etc.).

Is there an additional step or different process to hide the left-hand navigation (and potentially the top navigation) for either an entire site including Modern pages, or for specific Modern pages?

Also, is there a difference between SharePoint sites created by Teams, and regular SharePoint Online sites? I am doing most of my testing on my Teams site, and want to know if there are different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Last year, Microsoft released **site navigation visibility** feature using which I am able to hide the quick launch (left navigation) on team sites as well as top navigation on communication sites.

Read more about this feature release at: [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)

**Steps to hide site navigation**:

1. Go to SharePoint site home page (modern experience).
2. Click on Settings (gear) icon at top right corner
3. Select **Change the look** >> **Navigation**
4. Turn off **Site navigation visibility** & click Save.

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

I can see below options under "Change the look":

[image]

Under "Navigation" option, you can turn off the site navigation visibility.

Comment: Under "Change the Look", I have options grouped into Theme and Header. Neither has a Site navigation visibility option.

Comment: Which site template are you using, communication site or team site?